# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'selenium' on Vs code

Tags: python, selenium, wsl-2

I get this error when trying to run:

import selenium
from selenium import webdriver

I searched for a while and it seems to be an issue with the interpreter in the virtual env, cuz Selenium is indeed installed in the .venv\lib folder, however, so far I was not able to find any solution for it.
I am using

- Vs code
- WSL2
- python 3.9.7 (interpreter in VS code)

Comment: Did either of the answers to this question help? [VS code venv not detected (WSL)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63187229/vs-code-venv-not-detected-wsl)

Comment: Actually, no!
I created a file in \home but stil not working, besides, I have already installed Remote Extension for WSL... 

When I do 'which python' it shows me the right one (from the .venv inside workspace)

Comment: Okay, maybe another sort of environment problem specific to GUI.  How is your GUI support set up right now?  Windows 11 with WSLg?  Windows 10 with an X Server?

Comment: I am not sure if answer correctly, but I use W10 with WSL2, nothing else. 
I tried to run some old projects and I am having same issue with other packages...